# How to covert php data into json format?

Tags: php, json

Here i am fetching data using php code.But i want the same code to be convert into json format.I am not getting the way to do it.
I have tried it in this way.

my code

```html
 while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
        $result['name'] = $rows['name'];
        $result['id'] = $rows['id'];
    }
```

```html
  $res = json_encode($result);
    print_r($res);
```

getting result

```html
{"name":["sradha","nicky","demo","testing"],"id":["1","2","3","4"]}
```

Here i want it in this below json format

```
  [{id:1, name:'sradha'},
    {id:2, name:'nicky'},
    {id:3, name:'demo'},
    {id:3, name:'testing'}];
```

Please suggest me.
Any suggestion will highly appreciate.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please dont use `mysql_*`. It is deprecated and removed from PHP 7. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: ok..@Mr.Engineer Engineer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($filter)) {
    $result['name'] = $rows['name'];
    $result['id'] = $rows['id'];
    $new_result[] = $result;
}

$res = json_encode($new_result);
print_r($res);
```

**OR**

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($filter)) {
    $result[] = $rows;
}

$res = json_encode($result);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: @sradha And what about second one? What displays in first one?

Comment: if i am doing it for second one duplicate record is showing.
if instead of  mysql_fetch_array ,i am using mysql_fetch_assoc
its working.

other wise result is something like that

[{"name":"sradha"},{"id":"1"},{"name":"aruna"},{"id":"2"},{"name":"demo"},{"id":"3"},{"name":"testing"},{"id":"4"}]

Comment: Do not use print_r. Just use echo $res.

Comment: 1st result

[{"name":"sradha"},{"id":"1"},{"name":"aruna"},{"id":"2"},{"name":"demo"},{"id":"3"},{"name":"testing"},{"id":"4"}]

Comment: 2nd result

[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"sradha","name":"sradha"},{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"aruna","name":"aruna"},{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"demo","name":"demo"},{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"testing","name":"testing"}]

Comment: That means it is working but the issue is use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`.... And i just focus one your query which is related to getting data not duplicate....

Comment: So what it comes now, and i have updated my answer too.

Comment: Great! So fixed your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$result = array();

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($filter)) {
    $result[] = $rows;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: No need for this line  : `$result = array();`

Comment: It is not required but its always better to define it before using it because of scope

Comment: but i want only the name and id only.

Comment: the whole data is coming.any suggestion?

Comment: If other fields and values from query are not required then in your `SELECT` query you can fetch only `id, name`

Comment: ok,but how can i remove double "" from id and name 
i mean its coming like
[{"id":"1","name":"sradha"},{"id":"2","name":"aruna"},{"id":"3","name":"demo"},{"id":"4","name":"testing"}]

Comment: here is there any way i can remove the "" from id and name.
may be it create problem.

Comment: The output you're getting from json_encode is valid json data in php and it will not create any problem. But if you remoe double quotes then it will create problem

Answer (score 0):

Create your array like this

```
$i=0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
    $result[$i]['name'] = $rows['name'];
    $result[$i]['id'] = $rows['id'];
    $i++;
}
$res = json_encode($result);
print_r($res);
```

It will return output result